# How did Kamui's last act save the world?

Tags: x-1999

At the end of the Anime Series of X (*X/1999*). Kamui dies, so the Dragons of Earth would've won, thus allowing the destruction of the world.  However, Kamui creates a world wide barrier which prevents it.

From what I understand of the Barriers the Dragons of Heaven use, they allow damage caused within the barrier to not be carried into the real world, and the Barrier disappears when the caster dies. I think thta Kamui's final act in creating a world wide barrier has 2 flaws:

1. The destruction of the world had already started before the barrier was created.
2. Kamui died so the barrier shouldn't have been able to last.

So I am wondering, just how did Kamui's barrier save the world?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that he gave his all to the barrier so that it would be powerful and save the planet. A dying wish or something like that... It looked like that to me.